# Winforms listbox showing items twice

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I'm encountering an issue with a `Listbox` in a Winforms app, where it adds the entries twice, in an unexpected order.

[image]

```
private async void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Job.Start();

    await StartProgressTracking();
}

public async Task StartProgressTracking()
{    
    while (!Job.Progress.EndTime.HasValue)
    {
        await Task.Run(() => UpdateJobInformation());
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500));
    }
}

private void UpdateJobInformation()
{
    this.UIThread(() => 
    {
        listStepHistory.SelectedIndex = -1;
        listStepHistory.Items.Clear();

        listStepHistory.Items.AddRange(new ListBox.ObjectCollection(listStepHistory, Job.Progress.StepHistory.ToArray()));
        if (listStepHistory.Items.Count > 0)
        {
            //Select the last item (so that it scrolls to the bottom)
            listStepHistory.SelectedIndex = listStepHistory.Items.Count - 1;
        }
    });            
}

// The extension method that I'm using

public static void UIThread(this Control @this, Action code)
{
    if (@this.InvokeRequired)
    {
        @this.BeginInvoke(code);
    }
    else
    {
        code.Invoke();
    }
}
```

**Troubleshooting steps, so far**

- `listStepHistory` is not being referenced anywhere else in the code (other than the Designer.cs file, of course). It is not bound to a DataSource.
- I have doublechecked the `Job.Progress.StepHistory` property, it does not contain the same message twice. Every code is mentioned exactly once, as it should be.
- Initially, I thought this was a matter of multiple updates happening at the same time. However, I have decreased and increased the value of `Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500))` to extreme values (1,10,100,1000,10000) and have never seen more than two entries, also never less than two. This seems to exclude concurrent UI updates as the cause of the problem.

**Interesting to note**

If you look back at the screenshot, you will see that Winforms has selected the line with the highest code (numerically), this is consistent throughout the progress of the import job, the highest number is always the one that is selected. This makes sense, as I've ordered the codes before processing them, so they should be processed in numerical order.
If you look at the item after the one that is selected, you will see that this is a smaller code. This line (11004) is in fact **the same as the first line at the top of the listbox**. Similarly, the selected line (73109) is the same as the **bottom** line of the listbox.

In other words, the duplication happens as follows (and **bold** is **selected**):

> A B C D **E** A B C D E

This is weird, because I've instructed the listbox to select **the last item**. Notice the last step in my `UpdateJobInformation()` method:

```
if (listStepHistory.Items.Count > 0)
{
    //Select the last item (so that it scrolls to the bottom)
    listStepHistory.SelectedIndex = listStepHistory.Items.Count - 1;
}
```

Even if I had mistakenly added the items twice, I would expect the listbox to still select its **last** item (regardless of whether it's a duplicate or not), but that is not the case.

It seems to me that the duplicate entries are a "phantom entries". They get rendered to the screen, but they do not exist inside the `listStepHistory.Items` property.

I conclude from this that **the listbox is rendering something differently than what is contained in its `Items` property**.

Can anyone explain this behavior?

---

**Appendix**

As requested, the `Job` and `Job.Progress` interface/class definitions:

```
public interface IProgressTrackable
{
    ImportProgress Progress { get; }

    void Start();
    bool Cancel();
}

public class ImportProgress
{
    //redacted for brevity

    public List<string> StepHistory { get; set; } = new List<string>();
}
```

Comment: Looks to me like you're calling `StartProgressTracking()` multiple times in a loop. What's the loop for? Is it just polling every half second? I'd try to rule out reentrancy by changing the 500 msec to 10,000 just to see.

Comment: @EdPlunkett: `StartProgressTracking()` is not called from inside a loop. Also, though omitted from the the example in the question, the start button actually disables itself after clicking, you can't start it twice, also confirmed via breakpoints) I specifically mention tinkering with the delay time in my third troubleshooting step. The duplicate entries (always exactly double) seem to exclude concurrency issues (I would then expect more than 2 entries for an incredibly short delay, and for the problem to fix itself with a suffciently large delay, but neither is the case)

Comment: The reason the "wrong" item is selected is that you're adding the same list of actual object instances twice. When you tell it to select a given object, it finds the first object in `Items` *equal to* that object and selects it. The last object is in there twice, but the first appearance is the one it selects.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `UpdateJobInformation()` is called from the loop.

Comment: @EdPlunkett: Notice that I set `SelectedIndex`, not `SelectedItem`. `SelectedIndex` does not check for equality of the item. Also, where am I adding the list a second time?

Comment: I'm guessing that you might be adding the list a second time, in some way, because that's consistent with what you're seeing at runtime. As for SelectedIndex, I clearly need another cup of coffee. What's interesting though is I was able to reproduce what you're seeing with SelectedItem as I described, but SelectedIndex selected the last actual item.

Comment: What type is `Job`, so I can reproduce this?

Comment: @EdPlunkett: The first bullet point of my troubleshooting mentions that the listbox is not referenced **anywhere** else in code (except the needed references in Designer.cs of course, but there is no datasource defined in there either, only visual properties). I've double-(and now triple)-checked.

Comment: I believe that.

Comment: @EdPlunkett: Updated the question with the definitions. Note that `Job` is `IProgressTrackable` (an interface which all of my import jobs implement, so that the form works for all types of jobs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of using new ListBox.ObjectCollection, simply add the array

```
listStepHistory.Items.AddRange(Job.Progress.StepHistory.ToArray());
```

Comment: Nice find! I noticed that IEnumerable didn't work, and tried the `ObjectCollection` before I noticed that it takes arrays. Solved! It does seem very counterintuitive that `Listbox.Items.AddRange()` allows for an `ObjectCollection` parameter (whose constructor **always** requires a `Listbox` parameter), because it seems unavoidable to create duplicate entries this way... Nonetheless, thank you!